# UIWebView comparing current and defined URL's with a loop depending on result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, compare

I am trying to compare the current url in webView with a defined url say google.com

so in theory..

```
 NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];
 NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];
```

would give us our current url...

```
  NSString *newurl = @"http://www.google.com";
```

this would give us the compared to defined url

```
 while (!currentURL == newurl) {
  //do whatever here because currentURL does not equal the newurl
 }
```

Comment: `!a == b` means `(!a) == b` which is different from `!(a == b)`. And there is `a != b`. (Note that `==` doesn't compare content for NSStrings, see answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `-isEqualToString:`, like so:

```
while (![currentURL isEqualToString:newURL]) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

You can't use that to compare URLs to strings, tho', so you'll have to convert one or the other (converting newurl to an URL and comparing using `-isEqual:` might be a good move).

Comment: I tried that and get the following 

warning: 'NSURL' may not respond to '-isEqualToString:'
"-[NSURL isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
Any ideas?

Comment: @Syleron you should do it like this: NSURL *url; NSString *string; if (![[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:string]) {}

P.S. and read how to program in objective-c before you are writing programs please :)